# convert c# code files to one html file/s?

Tags: c#, .net, documentation

How i can convert to c# code files to html files?Is there any generation tool?

I need it my presentation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [CopyAsHtml](http://dotnetslackers.com/community/blogs/dsmyth/archive/2006/10/29/CopyAsHTML-Visual-Studio-2005-Add_2D00_in_2E00_.aspx) visual studio extension. It is written for VS2005 but can also [be used with VS2008](http://www.dotnetgeeks.com/blogs/dotnetgeek/archive/2008/04/04/Using-CopyAsHtml-Addin-with-VS-2008.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org) is a free documentation tool that among other things makes html files from source code.